# Configuring CentOS apache server to default to a specific port for ExpressJS and Node

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, node.js

Completely new to Linux and virtual private servers so please bear with me.

I have a webapp built on ExpressJS and NodeJS that runs on `port 5000` of my server, accessible via web by typing: `http://00.000.000.000:5000`. When you go to my non-port IP address (`http://00.000.000.000`) it shows the CentOS Apache setup welcome page.

I've tried running my Express app on `port 80`, but I get an `Address In Use` error.

What do I have to do to set up CentOS so that accessing its IP address at `00.000.000.000` loads up my Express app? I've tried adding `port 5000` to listeners in my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file but this did nothing.

Comment: For reference, if you like, you can use TEST-NET-1 (192.0.2.0/24) to substitute for IPs, instead of zeros.

Comment: You may want to read some documentation on how TCP/IP, basic ports and apache etc work before jumping in at the deep end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the `Address In Use` error because Apache is already listening on port 80.

If you want to access your Express app throught port 80, then you have to shutdown Apache and run your app on port 80.

Comment: Got it, cheers.